# Stretching image into quadrilateral

Tags: image, svg, transform

Is it possible to stretch an image into a quadrilateral (trapezoid), or transform the element so that it has no parallel sides?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html

yes you can - but you must do a path - points that makes up for trapezoid path - then show image using path

Comment: I think you don't understand, I want to scratch image in any quadrilateral, but not just cut image. see here: http://www.picamatic.com/show/2011/06/05/09/21/7607458_500x1349.png 1-original 2-cutting 3-scratching. you suggest #2

Comment: try this: http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-SVG-Transforms-20090320/#threed-rotate-z-definition

Comment: yes, this is the solution so far, thanks, unfortunately it is hard to find a browser that supports 3d transforms :)
edit your first answer or post another and I mark the answer as accepted answer/ if you want, of course, and if you can :)

Comment: The browser thing is a bitch - Chrome comes closest to SVG compliance

Comment: "Chrome comes closest to SVG compliance" - You guessed wrong. Opera is. http://www.codedread.com/svg-support.php